# Can I download code source from board?

Tags: arduino

I've uploaded source code to Arduino Mega board using Sketch. After that, I modified the original code. And later I needed the original code which was not modified for the other board, but I didn't back it up.

Is there any way I can download the source code from the board that I uploaded before?
Or is it possible to dump the original code from the board to another?

I heard there can be a way using ISP but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you haven't already, you might be better off asking this question on http://arduino.stackexchange.com and/or the official Arduino forums at http://forum.arduino.cc

Comment: You may want to look into using some form of [revision control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) in the future. It may seem like overkill for a tiny piece of Arduino source, but if used properly, you'll never lose an earlier version of your code again.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, note that the source code is never uploaded, only the compiled and linked binary. This reduces the usefulness of the result of the download.

The Arduino IDE uses `avrdude` to upload the compiled code to the board. The exact options it uses depend on the specific board chosen. If you have another similar board you can enable the "Show verbose output during upload" preference in order to see what exact command line is used for avrdude; once you have that you can replace the ":w:" with ":r:" and the filename that follows immediately after. Running that at the command line (using the correct path to the avrdude executable) will allow you to download the compiled code from the board.